# How do I create an exclusion into query results?

Tags: powershell

Forgive me for I am relatively new to PowerShell. I have an issue were we need to log off all disconnected users with the exception of one ID. I found this script which does a great job logging off the disconnected users. My question is how would I modify this section to ignore one or more specified users from the query results?

```
function Get-Sessions    
{
$queryResults = query session
$starters = New-Object psobject -Property @{"SessionName" = 0; "UserName" = 0; "ID" = 0; "State" = 0; "Type" = 0; "Device" = 0;}
foreach ($result in $queryResults)
{
  try
  {
     if($result.trim().substring(0, $result.trim().indexof(" ")) -eq "SESSIONNAME")
     {
        $starters.UserName = $result.indexof("USERNAME");
        $starters.ID = $result.indexof("ID");
        $starters.State = $result.indexof("STATE");
        $starters.Type = $result.indexof("TYPE");
        $starters.Device = $result.indexof("DEVICE");
        continue;
     }

     New-Object psobject -Property @{
        "SessionName" = $result.trim().substring(0, $result.trim().indexof(" ")).trim(">");
        "Username" = $result.Substring($starters.Username, $result.IndexOf(" ", $starters.Username) - $starters.Username);
        "ID" = $result.Substring($result.IndexOf(" ", $starters.Username), $starters.ID - $result.IndexOf(" ", $starters.Username) + 2).trim();
        "State" = $result.Substring($starters.State, $result.IndexOf(" ", $starters.State)-$starters.State).trim();
        "Type" = $result.Substring($starters.Type, $starters.Device - $starters.Type).trim();
        "Device" = $result.Substring($starters.Device).trim()
     }
  } 
  catch 
  {
     $e = $_;
     Write-Log "ERROR: " + $e.PSMessageDetails
  }
}
}
```

Thank you for any input you may have.

Comment: Would a simple `Where-Object` not suffice for this?

Answer (score 0):

So you want to omit certain results? You are using PowerShell objects so this should be easy with `Where-Object`

```
$omissions = "user1","user2"

foreach ($result in $queryResults)
{
    # Stuff inside the loop
} | Where-Object{$omissions -notcontains $_.Username}
```

Tack on the `where-object` and we use `-notcontains` to see if a given user is not in the array of `$omissions`. Which is of course a list of users.

**Caveat**

You might have issues with the output of that `foreach` construct. I have seen this in PowerShell versions earlier than 3.0. If that does happen you could just capture the `New-Object`s into an array to later filter or use `ForEach-Object`.